# AngularJS orderby filter without live update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a AngularJS project with a list of checkbox items .. I want all the selected checkbox at the top on "load"(init), but when I use a orderBy filter it will do the orderBy live - how can I prevent that?

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:'selected':true"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" /> {{item.desc}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

function FooController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {desc: 'test1', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test2', selected: true},
        {desc: 'test3', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test4', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test5', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test6', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test7', selected: true},
        {desc: 'test8', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test9', selected: false},
        {desc: 'test10', selected: false},
    ];
}
```

see the jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/a4uwz9aw/1/

Comment: You mean when you select a checkbox you dont want them to be ordered again? http://plnkr.co/edit/Dsug5X?p=preview

Comment: why don't you initially sort the `items` array in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case do not use orderBy on the view, instead sort it when you set the view model `items` in the scope itself.

Using native sort:-

```
   $scope.items = items.sort(function(itm1, itm2){
       return itm1.selected < itm2.selected ? 1:-1;
    });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dsug5X?p=preview)**

You can also use orderBy filter in the controller to perform ordering at once.

```
  $scope.items = orderByFilter(items, "selected", true);
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/shAwuK?p=preview)**

This way you abstract out the logic in controller itself.

Comment: Just what I needed - thanks .. used the orderByFilter ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
 <span ng-init="test=(items|orderBy:'selected':true) "></span>
```

look at t[he fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SanderElias/a4uwz9aw/2/)

if you need to resort, you can simply add a button to trigger the resort!

Comment: Please explain how to trigger the resort.

Comment: you can do it like this: `<button ng-click="test=(items|orderBy:'selected':true)">resort</button>`, However, this is putting a bit too much logic into the template to my taste, you should consider the answer from PSL, and do it in the controller. If you need to keep the originating array in tact. just sort into a new array, and use that in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BindOnce directive which only binds the data to DOM one way. So if you are only loading data and not adding new items this will do the trick.

see here: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

PS: This also increases the performance of your angularjs apps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since I got here from a Google search and had the exact same use case I figured I'd add an answer.

For this type of scenario you if you aren't adding or removing from the list a one-time binding does the job. Details can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding), but basically set the list as a one-time bound list using the `::` syntax like so:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="user in ::users | orderBy: ['-selected', 'name']">
```

Now, when the values of the name or the selected properties change the list won't re-sort, but the values will update in your model.